# How to retrieve data from multiple Many-To-Many database tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following tables as part of my Databases:-

[image]

But I am not sure if it is possible to retrieve the following related information (using Entity Framework inside my asp.net mvc web application), when passing the AccountDefinition.ORG_ID:-

- AaaUser
- AaaContactInfo

I have defined the following action method:-

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchTerm=null)
        {   var accountdefinition = repository.FindAccountDefinition(searchTerm).ToList();

            return View(accountdefinition);}
```

But how can i retrieve the above objects(AaaUser & AaaContactInfo) based on the AccountDefinition.ORG_ID value, and then pass the object to the view. baring in mind that the relation can either start from the AccountSiteMapping OR from the SDOrgContactInfo tables, as shown in the diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the include method in the repository.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: ya i know ,, but can not figure out how i can do this in my example. as there are one-to-many, one-to-one and many-to-many relationships , to retrieved the required info.

Comment: as i will need multiple .select and .include to the s.ame entity, which can not be achieved using EF

Comment: i define the following  "var relatedSD = entities.AccountDefinitions.Include(v=>v.SiteDefinitions.Select(a =>a.UserSiteMappings));" // but i can not retrieve the related DepartmentDefinition along with the UserSiteMapping.